# RestTemplate Connection Pooling Logs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, logging, resttemplate

Is there any way to find out or `log` the details of `RestTemplate` connnection pool, i want to make sure that `RestTemplate` is using custom connection pool configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using custom connection pool. Like `apache` `HttpClientConnection` which i used, apache provides `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` class which comprise of several useful methods like `getTotalStats()`, fulfilled my logs for pool stats .

```
@Autowired
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.getTotalStats();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can activate **DEBUG** level logging for `RestTemplate` containing package on your configuration file :

```
    logging:
      level:
        org.springframework.web: DEBUG
```

And don't forget to cutomize your `log4j2.xml`:

```
<Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT"
    ignoreExceptions="false">
    <PatternLayout
        pattern="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
</Console>
```

Another approach, you can add a break point on your `RestTemplate` and hence you can figure out whether it's taking your custom connection pool or not.

Hope that helps.